# Where to put pytest_generate_tests hook

Tags: pytest

I've written a decorator that can generate parameterized functions as [in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if not hasattr(metafunc.function, '_bdd_spec_test_runs'):
        return
    metafunc.parametrize(('name', 'index'), [(n, i) for (i, n) in enumerate(metafunc.function._bdd_spec_test_runs)])
```

If I have this at the bottom of the file where tests using my decorator appear it works. If however I move it to its own module (for example alongside the decorator itself) it results in my test not passing through it.

This seems to be because at the time that pytest sees that hook it has not yet collected the tests targeted yet. So Where am I supposed to put this function? Is there some way that I can tell pytest "here, this is the hook you should use after you're done collecting *all* tests".

Comment: Most probably `pytest` doesn't import the module containing the hook. Either create a file named `conftest.py` in the project root dir and put the hook in there (best solution), or pass your custom module by full import name via `-p` argument, e.g. `pytest -p mypkg.subpkg.mymod`.

Comment: @hoefling thanks the hook is in the same file as my decorator `bdd_spec.py` and that module is imported from my test file. I assumed that it was because the hook is being picked up too early but perhaps its because pytest doesn't parse that module like you say. I guess its not just examining all things loaded in the runtime?

Comment: Yes, importing the module with hooks from a test module is way too late, hooks should be registered before test collection. Use one of the ways listed above to ensure the hooks are loaded early. You can also register your custom modules as plugins via `pytest_plugins` in `conftest.py`, e.g. `pytest_plugins = ['mypkg.mymod']`.